# compare Image similarity using HOG

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Using python we need to find similarities between any type of image.

In the below code snippet, we are reading all images from the folder and extracting the histograms from them and storing the histograms in hashtable for comparision.

```
for imagePath in paths.list_images(imagesfolderpath):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

        if image is None or len(image)<=112:  
            print()
        else:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            winStride = (8,8)
            padding = (8,8)
            locations = ((10,20),)
            hist = hog.compute(image,winStride,padding,locations)
            labels.append(imagePath.split("/")[-2])
            if len(hist)>0: 
            data.append(hist)
            hashtable[imagePath] = hist
```

below code snippet is used for histogram comparision

```
for key, value in hashtable.iteritems():
    count+=1
    mydir = os.path.join(outpath, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f'))
    os.makedirs(mydir)
    for key1, value1 in hashtable.iteritems():
        score = cv2.compareHist(np.array(value, dtype=np.int8),np.array(value1, dtype=np.int8), cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA)
```

While histogram comparision the error encountered is as follows:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.depth() == CV_32F) in compareHist, file /home/administrator/Desktop/vijay/openface/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 2281
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestHOG.py", line 118, in <module>
    score = cv2.compareHist(np.array(value, dtype=np.int8),np.array(value1, dtype=np.int8), cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA)
cv2.error: /home/administrator/Desktop/vijay/openface/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:2281: error: (-215) H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.depth() == CV_32F in function compareHist
```

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. So here's the suggestion: ensure H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.depth() == CV_32F.

Comment: I think it is only needed to change the mat in compaeHist to be float values....